# Values are dropped out of quotation marks in the Laravel component

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade

Good day! I am studying Laravel 8. There is some problem when working with components. If a string with a SPACE in the component is transmitted from the blade template, then in the final HTML I have the following state:

```
<input type="text" class="rounded text-sm transition duration-200 ease-in" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Hello" world!="">
```

placeholder is a problem place

```
<x-my-input name="name" id="name" placeholder="Hello World!"></x-my-input>
```

MyInput.php

```
  <?php

namespace App\View\Components;

use Illuminate\View\Component;

class MyInput extends Component
{
    /**
     * Create a new component instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public $name;
    public $id;
    public $placeholder;

    public function __construct($name, $id, $placeholder)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->placeholder = $placeholder;
    }

    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View|\Closure|string
     */
    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.include.my-input');
    }
}
```

my-input.blade.php

```
<input type="text" class="rounded text-sm transition duration-200 ease-in"
   name={{ $name }} id={{ $id }} placeholder={{ $placeholder }}>
```

Comment: try quotes in my-input.blade.php .look like you have missed quotes for html attributes <input type="text" class="rounded text-sm transition duration-200 ease-in"
   name="{{ $name }}" id="{{ $id }}" placeholder="{{ $placeholder }}">

Comment: Thank you very much! This solved this error)